# windows8 store apps development

Tags: windows-store-apps

We need to develope a tool which can communicate with our storage device on Windows 8 tablet and Windows Phone 8 environment. Our design is like to have two modules, one to have UI controls and other to have device access (either DLL or EXE). We had planned to go with windows store apps for UI development but for the second module to access the device using file system IOCTL we didn't get clear reference point of how to implement. Kindly let us know how to use IOCTL from windows store apps or point us to a reference document. Thanks.

Comment: here is a example http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Custom-device-access-sample-43bde679

Comment: You cannot use IOCTLs in a store app.